# Dynamically changing theme in MVC3 with time duration

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guys I've read a lot of article and tutorials in the internet about how to dynamically change the theme in MVC3. But it doesn't seems to fit my need. 

I've read this bunch of tutorials 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/171695/Dynamic-CSS-using-Razor-Engine
http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/asp-dot-net-mvc-theme-supported-razor-view-engine
http://www.carlj.ca/2007/11/19/dynamically-applying-themes-to-your-aspnet-site-with-a-sitemap/
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article14.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18300/How-to-change-page-theme-in-asp-net-2-0-dynamicall
and a lot of more but doen't fit my need T_T. 

**Problem:** I want that my theme(style.css) to dynamically change from time to time without any click of buttons. It just spontaneously changing like lets say 30min for one theme to change to another one in a single page/view. (*Actually I even don't know if this is even possible*)

So far I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/171695/Dynamic-CSS-using-Razor-Engine) but seems not a complete approach.

My idea is this:
**I want style.css in my _Layout to change to style2.css after 30 minutes then change again to style3.css after another 30 minutes then loop back again to style.css and so on.** And where is the best way to do this approach? In the View? Controller? jquery? javascript? or whatsoever.  

I will greatly appreciate any suggestions and answers here. Thanks in advance..

**Edit2:**
Currently I've gathered one solution from Juann Strauss which uses javascript which I think have the concept on it

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" id="style" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetheme()
{
    alert('changing theme');
    var thestyle = document.getElementById("style");
    switch (thestyle.href)
    {
        case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")":
            thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style2.css")";
            break;
        case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style2.css")":
            thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style3.css")";
            break;
        case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style3.css")":
            thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")";
            break;
    }
}
setInterval(changetheme, (30 * 60 * 1000));
```

**Problem:** The `case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")":` shows a green wavy line which says *Syntax error in regular expression*. How could I possibly fixed it?

I have this another solution but also seems not working... T_T

**Codes:**

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" id="style" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetheme()
{
alert('changing theme');
var thestyle = document.getElementById("Site");
var href = '@Url.Content("~/")';

switch(thestyle) 
{
    case (href + '/Content/style.css'): (href + '/Content/style2.css');
        break;
    case (href + '/Content/style2.css'): (href + '/Content/style3.css');
        break;
    case (href + '/Content/style3.css'): (href + '/Content/style.css');
        break;
}
}

setInterval(changetheme, (30 * 60 * 10000 ));
```

Comment: Does every site user change en mass or is it independent for each user?

Comment: the themes are the same all through out the users. It only have that kind of scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

javascript. Create a function that changes your css source file and set its timeout to 30 minutes. This would work if the user stays on the page for 30 minutes.

If you want this to happen as the user is browsing your site, you're going to have to store the time the session started in a session variable and output the number of minutes since the last theme change as part of some dynamically-constructed javascript on the front-end.

If this is not clear enough, tell me and I'll write some code.

EDIT: the code

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" id="style" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changetheme()
    {
        alert('changing theme');
        var thestyle = document.getElementById("style");
        switch (thestyle.href)
        {
            case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")":
                thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style2.css")";
                break;
            case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style2.css")":
                thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style3.css")";
                break;
            case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style3.css")":
                thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")";
                break;
        }
    }
    setInterval(changetheme, (30 * 60 * 1000));
</script>
```

Comment: Cool thanks for your suggestion dude. Actually I'm also thinking that javascript will be one of the solution for this but I don't know how to do it T_T.. I will greatly appreciate it if you show me some codes. please. thanks.. :)

Comment: ahaha.. No I'm not.. Sorry I just finished eating my snacks.. :D As of now I'm going to mark it as the answer but I'm still going to test it. :)

Comment: Btw dude about your javascript where am I suppose to place it? is it directly on the View of my page or on the _Layout on my page? :D sorry I'm a bit noob..

Comment: If you want it only in one page, then somewhere on that page. If you want to to happen for every page, then put it in the head of your master page (_Layout).

Comment: dude I have a question. What if I'm using a format for href like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" type="text/css" id="style" /> what will be the look of the other parts of the code?

Comment: You can simply spit that out in the javascript too. e.g. thestyle.href = "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")";

Comment: how about the case "style.css":? am I just going to leave it that way?

Comment: No. you'll have to do the Razor stuff everywhere you're referring to the style sheets

Comment: ok.. sorry Im a bit noob.. what does it look like in the razor stuff in the case"style.css": ? T_T

Comment: case "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")"

Comment: ok thanks for all your suggestions and time dude.. but I can't get it work.. I need to translate your javascript to Razor from top to its cases.. atleast the logic is there.. :)

Comment: I had a hard time translating it in @razor. T_T could you help me again dude ? thanks again..

Comment: The case @Url dude shows a green wavy line that says "Syntax error in regular expression".

Comment: Use single quotes around the outside